# Windows Phone: Set Visibility of BindableApplicationBarMenuItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I am using "BindableApplicationBar.dll" in my Windows Phone project and I am looking for a way to set the visibility of "BindableApplicationBarMenuItem".
I gave a try to below code but Visibility="Collapsed" is doing nothing well.

```
<bar:Bindable.ApplicationBar>
        <bar:BindableApplicationBar Mode="Minimized">
            <bar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <bar:BindableApplicationBarMenuItem Visibility="Collapsed" Text="MyText/>
            </bar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </bar:BindableApplicationBar>
</bar:Bindable.ApplicationBar>
```

Thanks !

Comment: BindableApplicationBarMenuItem is dervied from framework element https://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BindableApplicationBar/BindableApplicationBar/BindableApplicationBarMenuItem.cs .  it should have visibility property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SushilMate : Thanks, I totally missed it. But still, I can't make it work. The binding visibility property is doing nothing. can you help me out with some example, if possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem, Like how you setting up visibility of menuitem. probably some snippets.

Comment: @SushilMate: Updated my question with code snippet

Comment: what's the BindableApplicationBar mode by default, when, you want to make menuitem collapsed when bar:BindableApplicationBar mode is minimized? if that so you need to use a trigger for that. for debugging purpose remove that mode = minimized & try to run the application.

Comment: @SushilMate : Mode is Minimized by default, removing it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my implementation from BindableApplicationBar to [cimbalino](https://cimbalino.org/) and now able to set IsVisible property on menu items.